# How to ignore a property update of the state in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I know that you can use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) to decide if render should be called or not. Citing the docs :

> By default, `shouldComponentUpdate` always returns true to prevent
>   subtle bugs when state is mutated in place, but if you are careful to
>   always treat state as immutable and to read only from props and state
>   in render() then you can override `shouldComponentUpdate` with an
>   implementation that compares the old props and state to their
>   replacements.

But my trouble is a bit different. I calculate a value in `componentDidUpdate` because a need a first render to be able to do my computation, and i'd like to store this value on the state to be able to use it later on in the `render` function, but I dont want to trigger a render when I modify it.

How would you do it ? Is this the proper way to go ?
Should I store this value somewhere else ? Directly on the `this` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute your state before component is actually updated.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  nextState.value = nextProps.a + nextProps.b;
}
```

Your component will get computed value with other changes and will update only one time.

Comment: Oh ! this is an interesting trigger indeed ! I did see it in the documentation, but only thought of it as a kind of life cycle notification point. I'll try that and keep you posted ! thx

Comment: To me, it seems to be good place to recompute state based on props. It's  something like `getInitialState`. Unlike `getInitialState`, it's triggered on every props (and state) update.